# Force implementation/definition of function declaration

Tags: c++, c, header, implementation

Suppose i have a header that should work in both C and C++.
This header contains some functions that the program must define, such as:

```
EXPORTED void * STD_API GetSymbol(CProject * p, char * s);
```

How can i ensure that these functions are actually defined somewhere? Even if the project actually compiles without, it is invalid because these functions will be looked up at runtime by another module (it is to be compiled as a module/dll/dylib/whatever).

The only thing i can think of is to use the definition somewhere, perhaps in a function call. However, that requires a function implementation in the header, which we all know will lead to multiple defintions.

In C++ you can probably get away with a hack like this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus

    static inline void _impcheck()
    {
        assert(0 && "_impcheck called.");

        GetSymbol(NULL, NULL);
    }

#endif
```

(because of how inline modifer allows multiple definitions). But how about c?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, C has `static` and `inline` too.

Second, how about...

1. **documenting** that the functions are to be implemented by the user?
2. **checking at runtime** the availability of the functions and reporting an error/throwing an exception when one can't be found? `dlsym()` (I assume you are using the `dlopen()` API, is that true?) will return a null pointer when it can't find a symbol.
3. If you really want a link-time failure, then you can try **using** the functions (call them, or assign their names to `volatile` function pointers if you don't want side effects to be performed prematurely, etc.)

Comment: Nice, i didn't know whether it actually was a supported feature (but it requires C99 iirc?) - i presume it has the same 'feature' as in C++.
1. I do that. 2. I do that as well. I have't ported fully to mac yet, but yes i will be using dl api most likely. 3. I wont do that :)
I just thought it would be a nice way to avoid common mistakes during compilation (if it could be implemented easily).

Comment: @Shaggi Yes, `inline` requires C99 "or later".

Answer (score 0):

C allows exactly the same `static inline` function.  But the compiler will probably optimize it away because your `assert` gets triggered so that following code is marked unreachable.

Comment: Was hoping compilation would fail anyway.. Ill figure something out.